# How I can get the element type of an array using RTTI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti

I'm using this code to get the element type of an array

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}    
uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils;

type
  TFooArray= array  of TDateTime;

Var
  T : TRttiType;
begin
  try
     T:=TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TypeInfo(TFooArray));
      Writeln(TRttiArrayType(T).ElementType.Name);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

but the application fails with an access violation on this line

```
Writeln(TRttiArrayType(T).ElementType.Name);
```

How I can get the element type of an array using the RTTI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cast is wrong the `TRttiArrayType` is for static arrays (and your array is dynamic), to fix the issue use the [`TRttiDynamicArrayType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/RTTI.TRttiDynamicArrayType) instead like so :

```
 Writeln(TRttiDynamicArrayType(T).ElementType.Name);
```

Comment: And it's also worth saying that forcing the type cast `TRttiArrayType(T)` or `TRttiDynamicArrayType(T)` is not a good habit. You should do it only if you are *sure* that the types match - which is not the case in your code. IMHO writing `(T as TRttiArrayType)` could make sense, or first test `if T is TRttiArrayType then...` which performs the same (but do not trigger any exception), but can be made once before a loop, for instance. It will avoid any similar type confusion.

Comment: Agree with Arnaud Bouchez, TSomeClass(VarSomeObj) is only applicable in `if VarSomeObj is TSomeClass then with TSomeClass(VarSomeObj) do Something`